# IIS RewriteRules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a RewriteRule that prepends "www" to the URL, granted that it does not already exist.

```
<rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The trouble is, I have another inbound domain (www.example2.com) for which I do not want this rewrite rule to apply. I would think that the following would work fine.

```
<rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example2.com" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But it just seems to be ignored. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this rule. It will add www, only for domain `example.com` and will ignore all other domains:

```
<rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Victor got me most of the way there. Thanks!

```
    <rule name="Add www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

patternSyntax has to be the default regular expression value. That means the URL pattern had to be altered, and the backtrack expression is zero-based.